# Fill a larger (empty) data frame based on a smaller one

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I just cannot come up with a method to fill a larger df based on a smaller one. I have a large empty data frame with two time columns (minutes and hours) and 12 other columns that contain NA elements.

On the other hand I have measurements that have been taken place in a specific "time tag" (for instance at h = 03 min = 33 or h = 14 min 21).

The larger data frame is bigger because it has "continuous time", and now I would like to fill in the values from the smaller data frame to specific rows. And the rows where I do not have any measured values, I want to keep them NA.

Haven't really found any clever way to do it...

Smaller dataset:

```
hours minutes color length 
0        0      B      1
0        15     G      2
0        30     R      2
0        45     Y      5
1        0      Y      3
1        15     Y      2
1        30     B      1
1        45     W      1
.
.
.
23       45     B       3
```

And the larger one:

```
hours minutes color length 
0        1     NA     NA
0        2     NA     NA
0        3     NA     NA
.
.
.
23       58    NA      NA
23       59    NA      NA
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: I edited the post, sorry for my bad formatting, don't know how to make create proper tables on stackoverflow

Comment: Try with `merge` or join and then do a coalesce

Comment: @akrun anyways, I would like to fill the second table just in the corresponding rows and keep the others untouched.. seems like an impossible task...

Comment: Or another option is `v1 <- do.call(paste, dfsmall[1:2]); v2 <- do.call(paste, dflarge[1:2]); i1 <- match(v2, v1)` and then use the index to assign the column values to the large data

Comment: That didn't really solve the problem. Merge function actually reduced the size of the larger data frame and mixed the order.

Comment: I meant a left join or left merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `left_join` for this.  As the last columns are empty in the large dataset, remove it while doing the join so that non-matching elements will be `NA` in the resulting dataset

```
library(dplyr)   
left_join(dflarge[1:2], dfsmall, by = c('hours', 'minutes'))
```

#### data

```
dfsmall <- structure(list(hours = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), minutes = c(0L, 
15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L), color = c("B", "G", "R", "Y", 
 "Y", "Y", "B", "W"), length = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

dflarge <- expand.grid(hours = 0:2, minutes = 1:59)
dflarge[c("color", "length")] <- NA
dflarge <- dflarge[do.call(order, dflarge[1:2]),]
row.names(dflarge) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thank you akrun for trying to help me, but I am still confused. What is that data snippet for?  Why can't I just use directly my existing data frames?

Comment: Oh I managed to create it. Still not 100% sure what happened in the data snippet, but it works anyways. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Avocado It is just to create a reproducible example.  The structure part is from `dput(dfmall)`